# Не переведена фраза в профиле

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, профиль-участника

В профиле пользователя (именно на вкладке "Профиль") не переведена фраза:

> (Вы не заполнили раздел *Обо мне*.)
>   Click here to edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Заменил](https://ru.traducir.win/string/10672) на:

> Нажмите здесь для редактирования

P.S. Вы можете предлагать свои варианты перевода, используя traducir (см.ссылку в начале сообщения). Ревьювер отберёт лучшие из них :)

Будет на сайте после синхронизации с движком.